# Generating a pre-signed URL in Python and then consuming it in Java

Tags: python, java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a Java-Python integration question, I'm receiving a pre-signed URL from a Python Lambda and a Java desktop client is actually using the URL to perform a multi-part upload.

The essence of the issue I'm facing is that the way Python and Java consumes a presigned URL is completely different. Python uses a JSON object like

```
{"url":"https://some-bucket-us-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com/","fields":{"key":"my_object_key","AWSAccessKeyId":"XXXXXXXXXXX","x-amz-security-token":"my_token","policy":"my_policy","signature":"my_sig"}}
```

Example usage of pre-signed URL in Python:

```
requests.post(returned_url_response['url'], data=returned_url_response['fields'], files=files)
```

However Java uses an actual URL that is parameterized/encoded in some fashion:

https://my-bucket-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/caseId%3D02_mock/dummy.encrypted?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210924T184139Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3599&X-Amz-Credential=some_credentialFaws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=some_hash

Example usage of pre-signed URL in Java:

```
URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);


// Create the connection and use it to upload the new object using the pre-signed URL.
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream())
```

My question is if there is a Java equivalent for doing what I did in Python so that I can still use the output generated by Python?

Alternatively will using `generate_presigned_url()` in the Python lambda generate a URL that I can use from the Java application? Will I need to generate a pre-signed URL for each ClientMethod operation `create_multipart_upload, upload_part, complete_multipart_upload`?

Finally, would either of the two approaches be preferable to just throwing out my Python Lambda and making a Java Lambda that generates a pre-signed URL instead?

Comment: Java [`URLDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can also generate an all-in-one encoded URL for any HTTP method, as that's the default form of a pre-signed URL. I created a test python script just to make sure that everything worked properly. If you run this (after exporting your credentials and replacing the variables with the appropriate bucket/object keys) you will get an encoded URL output to the console:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
url = s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': object_key},
                                ExpiresIn=expirationInSeconds,  
                                HttpMethod=method)

print(url)
```

It's likely that you're using `generate_presigned_post`, which returns a dict instead of a URL for your python lambda, however post operations will work fine using `generate_presigned_url` as long as you ensure you pass in the correct HttpMethod. ([reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url))

Comment: It turns out that since I was uploading multiple parts of a MPU that what I ended up needing was:

      `returned_url_response = client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='upload_part', Params={'Bucket': params['bucketName'],'Key': params['key'],'UploadId': params['uploadId'],'PartNumber': params['partCount']}`

Otherwise only the last part upload would be authorized and the others would fail because they were forbidden